# android.view.InflateException: Class is not a Drawable x

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

Our app has next exception in production:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
> res/drawable/ic_snowflake.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f080170 at
> android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:837)
> at
> android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:659)
> at
> android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:891)
> at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:833)  at
> android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:605)  at
> androidx.core.content.ContextCompat$Api21Impl.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:862)
> at
> androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:480)

caused by:

> android.view.InflateException: Class is not a Drawable x at
> android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromClass(DrawableInflater.java:218)
> at
> android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:143)
> at
> android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1322)
> at
> android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1281)
> at
> android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:824)
> at
> android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:659)
> at
> android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:891)
> at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:833) at
> android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:605) at
> androidx.core.content.ContextCompat$Api21Impl.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:862)
> at
> androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:480)

caused by:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class x cannot be cast to
> android.graphics.drawable.Drawable at
> java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:2467) at
> android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromClass(DrawableInflater.java:205)
> at
> android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:143)
> at
> android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1322)
> at
> android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1281)
> at
> android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:824)
> at
> android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:659)
> at
> android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:891)
> at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:833) at
> android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:605) at
> androidx.core.content.ContextCompat$Api21Impl.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:862)
> at
> androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:480)

Analyze production apk I found that file *res/drawable/ic_snowflake.xml* has next content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<x />
```

This happens because resource shrinker thinks that the specified resource is not used anywhere and replace it original content to `<x/>`. But that drawable is used by our next code:

```
class StateToViewModel() {
        
}
        
fun MyEnum.getIcon(): Int? {
    return when (this) {
        MyEnum.UNKNOWN -> null
        MyEnum.ONE -> R.drawable.ic_snowflake
        MyEnum.TWO -> R.drawable.ic_lock
    }
}
```

If we are place *getIcon* extension function inside companion object file *res/drawable/ic_snowflake.xml* save original content and crash goes away

```
class StateToViewModel() {
    companion object {
        fun MyEnum.getIcon(): Int? {
            return when (this) {
                MyEnum.UNKNOWN -> null
                MyEnum.ONE -> R.drawable.ic_snowflake
                MyEnum.TWO -> R.drawable.ic_lock
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question - why this happens? Why place where function is declared so important?

```
buildToolsVersion: 30.0.2 
kotlin-gradle-plugin: 1.4.30
minSdkVersion: 21
compileSdkVersion: 30
targetSdkVersion: 30
```

Comment: If is happening only on production my first suspect would be proguard, search if any proguard rules are needed for extensions